# List View button to VFP render as PDF. List view order is not respected

Tags: visualforce, pdf, list-view

Have a custom List View button which opens a VFP and renders the results as PDF. (easy stuff, standard controller and nothing funky). I would have thought that any sorting applied to the list view would be applied to my opening page. So if I sort on Deal Report Order then my PDF page would be sorted the same way.

Anyone know what I mean?  Should it work like that?

Here is the standard List View showing the sorting

[image]

I would expect the order on the VFP / PDF to show Account 1, 2, 3 and 4 in that order.

VFP

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accs" showHeader="false" 
  sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf" 
applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
```

then doing this

```
 <apex:repeat value="{! accs }" var="a">
```

Here is the full VFP

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accs" showHeader="false" 
  sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf" 
applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">

  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.tables}"/>


<head>


    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            margin: 1em;
            size: A4 Landscape;



            @bottom-left {
               /* content: "Date {!DAY(TODAY())}.{!MONTH(TODAY())}.{!YEAR(TODAY())}"; */
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 5px;
            }
            @bottom-right {
                content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 7px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }



        }




  table {

      -fs-table-paginate: paginate;


    }  

  thead {
        display: table-header-group;
        background-color: #fff !important;


  }



  table {
     font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 8px;
     width: auto;
  }

  tbody {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);


}

.logo-wrap tr {
  border-right: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

th, td th, {
  border-top: 1px solid #cbcbcb !important;
  text-align: center !important;


}

.pure-table .border-right th, .pure-table .border-right td{
    border-right: 1px solid #fff !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
     text-align: left !important;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 6px;
}

tr{
    text-align: center !important;
}

.nowrap-header{
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}

.grow{
  width: 100%;
}




</style>



</head>
<body>



     <table>   
         <tr class="border-right">
            <th><apex:image url="/resource/1433857887000/StarwoodLogo600x400" width="75" height="35"/></th>
         </tr>
        <tr class="border-right">
            <td style="font-weight: bold;">ACQUISTIONS PIPELINE</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="border-right">
            <td style="font-weight: bold;">SOF - Real Estate Pipeline</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border-right">
            <td>
              <apex:outputText style="font-weight: bold;" value="{0,date,MMMM dd, yyyy}">
                <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />
                </apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">


         <thead>


        <tr class="centre-cols">



         <th >
            Deal Name
         </th>
         <th>
            Stage
         </th>
          <th>
            Team
         </th>
          <th>
            Purchase Price
         </th>
         <th>
            Total SCG Equity
         </th>
         <th class="nowrap-header">
            Area <br/> (sq ft/sq m)
         </th>
         <th>
            Asset Class
         </th>
        <!--
         <th>
            Asset Type
         </th> -->
         <th>
            On/Off Marketing
         </th>
         <th>
            Bid
         </th>

         <th>
            Close Date
         </th>
         <th>
            SCG Office
         </th>
         <th>
            Transaction Facts
         </th>
         <th>
            Transaction Updates
         </th>
      </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{! accs }" var="a">  
          <tr>

            <td> ) &nbsp; <apex:outputField value="{! a.Name }"/> <br/> 
                        <div style="font-style: italic !important;">        <apex:outputField value="{! a.City__c}"/> <apex:outputField value="{! a.Country__c}"/> </div>


              </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Stage__c }"/>      </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Owner.Name }"/> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Purchase_Price_Rounded__c }"/> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Total_SCG_Equity_Rounded__c }"/> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Area_UOM__c }"/> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Asset_Class__c }"/> </td> 
          <!--  <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Asset_Type__c }"/> </td> -->
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.On_Market_Off_Market__c }"/> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Bid__c }"/> 
                      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Bid_Date__c }" /> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.Close_Date__c }"/> </td> 
            <td>      <apex:outputField value="{! a.SCG_Office__c }"/> </td> 
            <td style="text-align: left !important;  display:block" >      <apex:outputText value="{! a.Transaction_Facts__c }"  escape="false"/> </td> 
            <td style="text-align: left !important;" >      <apex:outputText value="{! a.Transaction_Updates__c }"  escape="false"/> </td> 

          </tr>

        </apex:repeat>

      </tbody>
    </table>



</body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post a screencast to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Thought it was working, but it's not. I havent posted the PDF output, it's just a bog standard page (standard controller) and displays a table of the accounts.

Comment: What does the visual force page look like when you press the Run Deal report button? Are you querying for these accounts in your page?

Comment: Just add the code

Comment: nothing crazy, no extension

Answer (score 1):

At the root of your problem is that you can't have any active content in a PDF. Anything that's "active" will either be ignored or cause your page to explode and not render at all. Without having seen your page code, I'm presuming what's happening is that any buttons you've used to set a sort order are being ignored, causing the page to render using the default sort order.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The button is not performing the sort. It opens a VFP for the result set from the standard List view. In fact regardless of my sorting column in the List view (e.g. I could even be sorting on the account name) that order in the list view is not the same order in the VFP. Hope that helps.

Comment: If that's the case, please post the rest of your VF code. There may be something else going on in your code related to [Component Behavior When Rendered as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm) causing issues.

Comment: added the main code to the post - hope you can spot something

Comment: I don't see anything at all unusual about your code. From your description, it sounds to me as though the list view controller is resetting itself and performing the query again before rendering the PDF. In essence, the view state isn't being maintained. That's why it changes regardless of what you sort on, including account name.

Comment: @crmprogdev thank you, I was wondering if there's any option to render PDFs in lightning components? Do you think this feature will be available down the road?

Comment: @AtlasCan Yes, you can render from a Lightning component now. There are several strategies for doing this. You'll find a number of posts on it in the forum if you search for them. Some use a JS library and others print to a VF page. Is up to you to decide which approach works best for you. I've only done the latter.

Comment: oh, I meant as a native solution without embedding a vf page. I should test the JS library. Thank you @crmprogdev.